# How to address nullpointer exception in the app by letting the application to continue the task without too many null checking with Spring

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception

I would like to know if there is a clean way of handling null pointer exception in the mapping without too many null checking. For the following code there are different ways of handling null checking:

```
record.getFoos().forEach(foo -> foo.setBar("Bar!")); //record.getFoos() might be null
```

**Option 1:**

```
if(record.getFoos() !=null){
} else {
// set default value
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
Optional.ofNullable(record.getFoos()).ifPresent(foo -> foo.setBar("Bar!")).orElse(new Bar("Default"));
```

**Option 3:**

Use a customer deserializer at the mapping of JSON to POJO objects to ensure that none of the mandatory properties is null and replace with the default value.

No comment about **Option 1**, as it is properly the worst option when it comes to the amount of code we need to write.

I guess you may think there is nothing wrong with **option 2**, but the issue with that is there are going to be too many places and ensuring none of the mandatory properties is null. This is not going to be really scalable if you are dealing with thousands of properties and tons of permutations.

**Option 3** also seems to be fine, but it gets error-prune and not scalable as we need to ensure for any new property the deserializer gets updated and this can easily get out of the sync.

I was wondering if there is another way with Spring framework where we can somehow define an approach that whenever the null pointer exception is thrown within a certain package then instead of exiting the method continue the work and use a default value for the corresponding object? In that case, we just need to say that the default value for `Bar` is `"Default"`.

Comment: The cleanest approach in this particular case is to [use an empty collection instead of null](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern). With Jackson, you can simply do this by saying `List<Foo> foos = new ArrayList()<>;` in your `Record` class.

Comment: It's option 3? Isn't it? Is there a way I can set Jackson to do it in bulk instead of specifying them one by one?

Comment: You _should_ do it individually. When you are using those DTOs in other places (for example, testing), you want them to start in a consistent state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is worth to mention a few best practices the are usually used to avoid this kind of issues:

- As pointed out by @chrylis -on strike-, you should really avoid using `null` collections. **Always use empty collections** in that case.
- Don't put `null` elements in the collection as well. There is rarely a valid reason to do so honestly.
- If null elements are just part of a temporary state, you can easily filter nulls:

```
record.getFoos().stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .forEach(it -> . . .)
```

- `Optional.ofNullable(. . .).orElse(. . .)` is usually good way to handle something and give default value instead. You can easily create a utility method to handle that in the scale. E.g.

```
public static  <T> T defaultIfNull(T nullable, T defaultVal) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(nullable).orElse(defaultVal);
}
```

- You should never try to cath `NullPointerException` and try to handle it. It's a slippery road which leads to hell :)
- If you deserialize nullable entity and have default value having this code:

```
public class JavaObject 
{
   @JsonProperty("some-value")
   public String someValue = "default-value"; // set default value

   @JsonSetter("some-value")
   public void setSomeValue(String s) {
    if (s != null) { // check for null assingment
        someValue = s; 
    }
}
```